# How to toggle layer visibility in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects

ILayer.Visible seems to have no effect - How can I manually manage layer visibility and actually get the map control to update?

```
ILayer lyr = mapControl.get_Layer(i);
```

//this works for custom layers that I define but not for Bing_Maps.lyr or ESRI .lyr files that comes with ArcEngine or connections to ArcGIS Online.  For composite layers, I also tried iterating through sub layers and setting the visibility to false

```
lyr.Visible = false;
mapControl.Update();
mapControl.Refresh();
mapControl.ActiveView.Refresh();
mapControl.Invalidate();
```

Comment: are you refreshing or partially refreshing the active view's display? By "manually" do you mean programmatically?

Comment: Can you share your code? ILayer.Visible Property is the one which is used for this, & is working for me.

Comment: edited code formatting

Comment: I added more code and a better description to answer your questions.  I did see another post about ILayerFile and noticed that this interface has no visibility property - would it have anything to do with that?

Comment: I experienced problems with layer visibility while using the DynamicDisplay functionality.

Comment: If you get super desperate you can observe a Map Extent changed and Add / Remove ILayer manually.  I do this.

Comment: This wouldn't be an issue if Esri implemented INotifyPropertyChanged the way Silverlight/WPF apps do.

Answer (score 2):

If the layer is added to a basemap layer you need to Notify the baselayer that a layer has changed to ensure that it recreate it's display cache: [Accessing a basemap sublayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000001vz000000.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a ITOCControl, you can take a look at this feature[ITOCControl.LayerVisibilityEdit](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/arcobjects/esricontrols/ITOCControl_LayerVisibilityEdit.htm)
Hope this helps